# Python 3: Finding the Sum of Values inside a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

[This is the question on my homework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqrgr.png)

Below is my attempt on solving it:

```
def printStocks(d):
for key, value in d.items() :
    print(key, "\tPrice: ", value[0], "\tAmount: ", value[1])
    sum_items = 0
    sum_items += value[0]*value[1]
print("Total value of all items: ", sum_items)
    
d_1 = {"banana": [4, 5], "apple": [2, 2], "orange": [1.5, 2.5], "pear": [3, 4]}

printStocks(d_1)
```

Although the Debug is this:

```
Part-2
banana  Price:  4   Amount:  5
apple   Price:  2   Amount:  2
orange  Price:  1.5     Amount:  2.5
pear    Price:  3   Amount:  4
Total value of all items:  12
```

So the problem is that the total value of all items should be 39.75

Since: 4x5 + 2x2 + 1.5x2.5 + 3x4 = 39.75;

I don't understand why it says 12 as the sum_items value. I am lost right now, could get some little help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even *try* using a debugger?

Comment: No, I have never tried using any, by the way I am very new to this website, therefore I make a lot of mistakes on formatting although I try so hard not to. So apologies for them. Lastly do you have recommendation of any debugger ???

Comment: I also have another thing to say which is: in this website I have experienced that whenever I ask a question it gets very good and very explaining answers which is the best thing, but there are also people that come to the posts and rip you apart in sarcastic ways just for the smallest mistakes. Everybody can make mistakes. I mean its not cool there are tons of new learners out there, right? I mean we ask questions to see where is the mistake and learn from them, not to get dragged through the mud because of the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your `sum = 0` out of loop. In other case it will be zero after every iteration

Comment: Dont be sorry, everyone started someday :) I recommend you to install Visual Studio Code, it has build in debugger, you can install some add-ons related with python that helps you edit and debug code. You can also run code into terminal build in into editor which helps a lot at the beggining. Feel free to ask questions here, but before you did so, try find out if someone else had this problem before you.

Answer (score 1):

You reinitialize the sum_items variable in each loop in for-loop. You should put the sum_items = 0 outside the for-loop.